# Grayscale filter in Safari 5

Tags: jquery, css, grayscale

I know this question has been asked already but I could not find straight answer for it

I am trying to show some images on a page where they should be shown in grayscale, except on mouse hover when they smoothly transition into color. I’ve made it work nicely on IE, Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn’t work on Safari 5.x. The problem is on Safari 5 for Mac and Safari for Windows.

I'm using following code

```
img{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease; /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Fix for transition flickering */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 filters are supported by very few browsers at the moment.

You can try this https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/jQuery.BlackAndWhite

Look this http://caniuse.com/css-filters